# References on coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, coherent-states

I've begun my Master degree final work and I was asked to study in details coherent states. The goal is to apply them to a QFT formalism for a scalar potential effectively decribing the weak field limit of the graviton field. In particular (I've read that squeezed coherent states are well suited in the description of low energy vacuum fluctuations). Therefore, I wanted to ask for the best references and reviews of the above topics, since I've found a jungle of papers which often drives me off-topic as they are related to many other branches of physics. My starting references were:

- "Coherent states in field theory" W. M. Zhang.
- "Searching for Coherent States: From Origins to Quantum Gravity" P. Martin-Dussaud.
- "Coherent States. Some Applications in Quantum Field Theory and Particle Physics" B. Skagerstam.

Comment: Have you checked any of the sources from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states_in_mathematical_physics)? Eg Gazeau's book, Perelomov's book? How about Glauber and Sudarshan and collaborators' original papers?

Comment: + Klauder and Skagerstam coherent states book

Comment: Thank you all guys! I have already found the Gazeau book, which I think is the best way to get into the subject. However, what I was searching was something about the secondo part of Klauder and Skagerstam mentioned above. If you know more recent references of this type I'll be grateful.